# Access Firefox from Terminal without Opening Firefox Window

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, firefox

I would like to access a website using Firefox in Ubuntu from the terminal. I must do this *without opening a Firefox window* because my computer has no screen.

How can I do this?

Note: I am running an external program to capture Firefox traffic.

Comment: Look into `Xvfb`.

Comment: firefox is GUI browser. what do you mean by running firefox without gui? you may use text/cli browser.

Answer (score 1):

***Access the Internet from a Command Line***

If you are trying to access websites in the form of text, inside of a terminal, then I suggest you look into text-mode web browsers. Here are a list of a few popular ones:

- ***ELinks:*** ELinks is an advanced and well-established feature-rich text mode web (HTTP/FTP/..) browser. ELinks can render both frames and tables, is highly customizable and can be extended via Lua or Guile scripts. It is quite portable and runs on a variety of platforms.
- ***Lynx:*** Lynx is a fully-featured World Wide Web (WWW) client for users running cursor-addressable, character-cell display devices (e.g., vt100 terminals, vt100 emulators running on PCs or Macs, or any other character-cell display).
- ***W3M:*** w3m is a text-based web browser as well as a pager like `more' or`less'. With w3m you can browse web pages through a terminal emulator window (xterm, rxvt or something like that). Moreover, w3m can be used as a text formatting tool which typesets HTML into plain text.

***Read more into these options below:***

https://askubuntu.com/questions/29540/browsing-the-internet-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Check out a cli web browser! https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications/Internet#Console

If you want to automate/script your procedure, Beautiful Soup may be of use depending on what you are trying to do.

Best of luck!